# We have two version of the same assembly in GAC? I want my client to make choice of which assembly to choose?

Tags: c#, assemblies

We have two version of the same assembly in GAC? I want my client
to make choice of which assembly to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your config file:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="clsLibVsn"
publicKeyToken="b035c4774706cc72"
culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion= "1.1.1830.10493"
newVersion= "1.0.1830.10461"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

You need to specify “bindingRedirect” in your config file. For ins
in the above case “clsLibVsn” has two versions “1.1.1830.10493” and “1.0.1830.1
from which “1.1.1830.10493” is the recent version. But using the bindingRedirect we can s
saying “1.0.1830.10461” is the new version. So the client will not use “1.1.1830.10493”.

Answer (score 5):

You can program your application to edit app.config file. You should write something similar to this:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="yourassembly" publicKeyToken="96D09A1EB7F44A99" culture="neutral"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.8.0" newVersion="2.2.8.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

in your app.config. This will allow to specify assembly version your application needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class and its static CreateInstance method which has number of overloads. You can specify the full assembly name in a format like *System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089*

Comment: You might need to define an Interface in some "Common" assembly which your application and those two versions of assemblies reference and some classes in those assembly implement. After CreateInstance you can Unwrap the object to that interface and use!